# Convert Joomla 1.0 table content into 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have tried to convert my running Joomla 1.0.13 into a newer version several times, but I never succeeded. The migrator component seem to return wrong output due to German Umlauts (Special Characters) and therefore I have burried my plan to use it.

I would be a lucky man, if I just could migrate the articles in the jos_content table of Joomla 1.0 and move it over to the latest version 2.5.

When I compare the new table structures, I see actually a few things have changed.
**Does any body know how the table columns in version 1.0 can be mapped to 2.5?**
Is it possible to convert entries?

Note that I am okay, with losing some informations like categories. Or that every article points to the same category.

I have posted a comparison of the jos_content table structure at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/RRFaqxk4

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to run a 1.5 installation and have it do the 1.0 to 1.5 migration for you. Then use JUpgrade or SPUprgade to go 1.5 to 2.5 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Before migrating, you should always try and upgrade the latest version of the Joomla series you're using. this will ensure migrations run more smoothly and be less likely to have any glictches.

There are not migrations tools for Joomla 1.0 to 1.5 on JED so read [this documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable) on how to do it. Once done, download and install [JUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658), which will allow you to migrate from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5.

Do note that after migrations, some of the 3rd party extensions you're running won't work and will need to be updated too.

Hope this helps